# Hover to scroll down div and auto scroll to top when mouseleave

Tags: jquery

Hye. I'm currently working on this jquery codes and this codes work fine. But as my understanding in jquery is very limited, I can't really tweak the codes to meet my needs.

So, I want to scroll down the ".punchmeintheface" div when hovering onto it and at the same time I want to auto scroll the div back to top when mouseleave.

```
<div class="punchmeintheface">
   <img src="http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/2333/q4sl.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

and the jquery

```
var amount = '';
function scroll() {
    $('.punchmeintheface').animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 100, 'linear',function() {
        if (amount != '') {
            scroll();
        }
    });
}
$('.punchmeintheface').hover(function() {
    amount = '+=20';
    scroll();
}, function() {
    amount = '';
});
```

and the css if needed

```
  .punchmeintheface {
    width: 640px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y:auto; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

This is my current work : http://jsfiddle.net/sandalkoyak/GhLCt/

Please take a look and help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit this part

```
$('.punchmeintheface').hover(function() {
    amount = '+=20';
    scroll();
}, function() {
    amount = '0'; //<----- here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GhLCt/1/

Comment: hey man! this is awesome!! but is there any chance to make it scroll up a bit slower? but this is cool enough actually! thanks!

Comment: If you want it slower just change animate time to this: `amount === '0' ? 500 : 100`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GhLCt/5/